# How to show the slope of converged function of the Contraction Mapping Theorem is bigger in this case?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Suppose I have the following recursive equation that satisfies in every $x\in(0,1)$ : $$v(x) = g(\alpha)\cdot F(x,v(x))$$
where $v(x)$ is a function of $x$, and $g(\alpha)$ is a strictly increasing function with $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Suppose that, regardless of $\alpha$, the RHS satisfies all the sufficient conditions to apply the Contraction Mapping Theorem in sup norm and that $F$ transforms a strictly increasing function to another.

My guess is that **both** $v'(x)$ and $v(x)$ are increasing with $\alpha$, but I am struggling to prove it.

---

Here is how I understood Ali's proof for the case of $v(x)$ increases with $\alpha$ in every $x$, but I think I missed to specify that **$F$ is a contraction mapping with sup norm in functional space**.  Please let me know if I'm the one wrong.

$F$ is a contraction mapping for function to function. Therefore the last step does not necessarily satisfy the definition of contraction mapping on sup norm.

(1) What I want to show is that $v(x)>\tilde{v}(x)$ for any $x$.

(2) For $\alpha < \alpha'$, I get $v(x)= g(\alpha)F(x,v(x)) < g(\tilde{\alpha})F(x,v(x)) $ for every $x$

(3) I define $ v=$ f.p. $T_{\alpha}$ and $\tilde{v}=$ f.p. $T_{\tilde{\alpha}}$.

(3-1) Dropping out $x$ for simplicity, $v =T_{\alpha}(v)=g(\alpha)F(v) < g(\tilde{\alpha})F(v)=T_{\tilde{\alpha}}(v)$ for any $x$

(4) Suppose, on the contrary, $v(x) \geq \tilde{v}(x)$ for **some $x$**.

(5) $|v(x)-v'(x)| < |T_{\tilde{\alpha}}(v(x)) - T_{\tilde{\alpha}}(\tilde{v}(x)) | $

Up to my knowledge, (5) does not necessarily contradicts the definition of contraction mapping defined on functional space with sup norm : $ sup|T_{\tilde{\alpha}}(v)-T_{\tilde{\alpha}}(\tilde{v})| \leq sup|v-\tilde{v}| $.
It is because the contradiction is only for **some** $x$.

Comment: I made some big edits to my answer that you may not have seen. Hopefully it's a lot more useful now!

Comment: I'm finding this a little hard to parse. Please fix your notation. When you write $F(x,v(x))$ it can only mean that $F$ acts on the evaluation of $v$ at a certain point $x$, not on the function $v$ itself.

Comment: Sorry I tried to as much as precise. I hope it helps. Thank you very much!

Comment: But it still says $F(x,v(x))$.

Comment: Hmm.. then I don't get it. It is not sufficient to say that the recursive equation should hold for every $x$?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $x$ fixed and write
\begin{equation*}
    T_{\alpha}(u)=g\!\left(\alpha\right)F\!\left(x, u\right).
  \end{equation*}

To show that $v=\text{f.p.}\,T_{\alpha}$ is a strictly increasing function of $\alpha$ it will be enough that
\begin{equation*}
  \alpha < \alpha' \implies T_{\alpha}(u) < T_{\alpha'}(u)
\quad\text{for all }u
\end{equation*}
because then
\begin{equation*}
  \alpha < \alpha' \implies
\text{f.p.}\,T_{\alpha}=
T_{\alpha}\left(\text{f.p.}\,T_{\alpha}\right)
    < T_{\alpha'}\left(\text{f.p.}\,T_{\alpha}\right)
  \end{equation*}
so if for some $\alpha < \alpha'$ it *were* the case that
$ \text{f.p.}\,T_{\alpha'} \le \text{f.p.}\,T_{\alpha}$
then
\begin{equation*}
    \left\vert \text{f.p.}\, T_{\alpha}-\text{f.p.}\,T_{\alpha'}\right\vert <
    \left\vert T_{\alpha'}\left(\text{f.p.}\, T_{\alpha}\right)
      -\text{f.p.}\,T_{\alpha'}\right\vert
=\left\vert T_{\alpha'}\left(\text{f.p.}\, T_{\alpha}\right)
      -T_{\alpha'}\left(\text{f.p.}\,T_{\alpha'}\right)\right\vert
  \end{equation*}
which is impossible since $T_{\alpha'}$ is a contraction.

The condition is met with your assumptions plus one additional—that $F\!\left(x, u\right)$ takes only positive values.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer Ali. I really appreciate it !

Comment: Dear Ali, I am not sure if I understood your proof correctly (I thought I did, but relooking on it, I got confused).